# git merge direction as it relates to submodules

Tags: git

I have a master branch A and a topic branch T, and they are both pointing to a submodule S.
Some work was done on both A and T, and the work done in T moved submodule S ahead by a few commits.

Now I wish to merge my topic branch into the master branch and what I have found is that if I am on the master branch and run `git merge T` then the submodule pointer is not moved by the changes in branch T.

If I am on topic branch T and run `git merge A` then the submodule S is now at the location that was moved ahead in topic branch T.

It seems that which branch you do the merge from determines which submodule location the merge takes.  Is this behaviour as intended?  Any ideas on how to prevent losing the new submodule location, or do you need to be on the correct branch before doing a merge?

Comment: The pointer to submodule gets updated from the merged branch, but the git repository in submodule directory does not get checkouted to the new pointer. You should run git submodule update to get it checkouted to the current pointer.

Comment: I use submodules because they solve a problem, but there's a lot of pitfalls while using them. Check this article: http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/

Comment: @OndřejMirtes What I'm finding is that the submodule does not get updated to the merged branch, even if I run submodule update

Comment: "the work done in T moved submodule S ahead by a few commits": did you go in the parent repo and commit (registering the new SHA1 for S)?

Comment: Yes, the parent repo had the new SHA1 for S moved in one of its commits

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `git submodule` isn't showing what you expect.  A walkthrough:

```
# setup
git init t; cd t
git init subrepo
( cd subrepo; touch .gitignore; git add .; git commit -msubinit )
  git submodule add ./subrepo;  git add .; git commit -msubadd

# advance topic's subrepo
git checkout -b topic
( cd subrepo; touch new; git add .; git commit -mnew )
git add .; git commit -msubnew

git submodule status
(cd subrepo; git rev-parse HEAD)
git submodule status --cached
git rev-parse :subrepo
git status

git checkout master
git submodule status
(cd subrepo; git rev-parse HEAD)
git submodule status --cached
git rev-parse :subrepo
git status

git merge topic
git submodule status
(cd subrepo; git rev-parse HEAD)
git submodule status --cached
git rev-parse :subrepo
git status

git checkout -b demo master~
(cd subrepo; git rev-parse HEAD)

gimme=`git rev-parse :subrepo`
(cd subrepo; git checkout $gimme)
```

A nested repo is a submodule, and vice versa. `git submodule` helps with some administrative tasks. It's not very hard to do without the command completely.